# Unable to apply function on last item in the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

colorMe is a function to color matched string for each user .I'm calling colorMe function from here:

```
 $(function()
{
    //alert("default");
    $('#contents').append("<table><tr>");
    var globalStore = {};
    globalStore.data = [];
    var data;
    $.when(
    // 1st query
    $.get('/search/show_all_tutors.php',function(data){globalStore.data = globalStore.data.concat(data);console.log(data)},"json")
).then(function() {

     var j=0;
     var plus; 
     var neg; 
     localStorage.size = globalStore.data.length;
    for (i = 0; i < globalStore.data.length; i++) {

 colorMe(globalStore.data[i].morning,globalStore.data[i].afternoon,globalStore.data[i].evening, globalStore.data[i].UUID,i);

<div class='small-6 medium-6 large-6 columns text-left day morning_"+globalStore.data[i].UUID+"' id='"+globalStore.data[i].UUID+"'>Morning: <span class='Mon'>M </span><span class='Tue'>T </span><span class='Wed'>W </span><span class='Thrs'>T </span><span class='Fri'>F </span><span class='Sat'>S </span><span class='Sun'>S</span></div><div class='small-6 medium-6 large-6 columns text-left day afternoon_"+globalStore.data[i].UUID+"' id='"+globalStore.data[i].UUID+"'>Afternoon: <span class='Mon'>M </span><span class='Tue'>T </span><span class='Wed'>W </span><span class='Thrs'>T </span><span class='Fri'>F </span><span class='Sat'>S </span><span class='Sun'>S</span></div><div class='small-6 medium-6 large-6 columns text-left day evening_"+globalStore.data[i].UUID+"' id='"+globalStore.data[i].UUID+"'>Evening: <span class='Mon'>M </span><span class='Tue'>T </span><span class='Wed'>W </span><span class='Thrs'>T </span><span class='Fri'>F </span><span class='Sat'>S </span><span class='Sun'>S</span></div>

...................................
```

And this is the colorMe function

sample data:

```
param = 'Sat,Sun';
param_af = 'Mon,Fri,Sat';
param_eve = '';
param2 = '13 digit user id';
index = denotes nth call to the function
```

```
    var userarray = [];
var dayarray  = [];
var dayarray2 = [];
var dayarray3 = [];
function colorMe(param,param_af,param_eve, param2,index)
{
var data = 0;   
    console.log("index= "+index);

    /*console.log("DAY "+param);
    console.log("user "+param2);*/
    //console.log("k= "+k);
    console.log("data= "+data);

    userarray.push(param2);
    //console.log("mY "+userarray[k]);
    dayarray.push(param);
    dayarray2.push(param_af);
    //console.log("afternoon "+dayarray2[k]);
    dayarray3.push(param_eve);
    //console.log("evening "+dayarray3[k]);
    //console.log("Day "+dayarray[k]);
    var k = userarray.length;
    console.log("K= "+k);

    for(;data < k;data++)
    {
        //console.log("data="+ data);
    var arr = dayarray[data];
    var arr2 = dayarray2[data];
    var arr3 = dayarray3[data];
    console.log("userdata= "+userarray[data]);
    $("div.morning_"+userarray[data]+" span").each(function() {
                if(arr.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {

                  $(this).css("color","#26F525");

                }
            });


            $("div.afternoon_"+userarray[data]+" span").each(function() {
                if(arr2.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {

                  $(this).css("color","#26F525");

                }
            });
            $("div.evening_"+userarray[data]+" span").each(function() {
                if(arr3.indexOf($(this).attr("class")) > -1) {

                  $(this).css("color","#26F525");

                }
            });

    }
    k++;
    //if(data == (localStorage.size-1)){
//alert("data"+data+" k= "+k+"size= "+localStorage.size+"user= "+param2+"morn= "+param+"aftr="+param_af+"eve="+param_eve);  

    //}
}

                }
```

> **How to apply `colorMe` function on the last item also?**
>
> **Narrowed explanation**
>
> I have a first loop that has 10 items.
>
> Each item calling to a  colorMe function to color its content in
>   green.
>
> It suppose to color all the 10 items but now it only colors 9. The
>   last one always missed.
>
> **Now how do I make the last item also to be colored?**

Comment: Any chance you could narrow this down to the actual problem?  Have a read of this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @freedomn-m, take a look at Narrowed explanation in my post

Comment: I don't find this particularly readable. What's `data` in that code? I don't see it anywhere except when it's used. Why are you using parallel arrays instead of a single array of objects?

Comment: @DaveNewton var data = 0;. I updated my post

Comment: It seems crazy to use a global for a local loop counter, and if you call the function more than once, completely broken.

Comment: $.when is misleading as you don't use it properly. Your call to $.get() return a promise you should place inside $.when(). Call then() on $.when

Comment: @Karen the relevant part of mcve is not the explanation of the problem, it's creating a *minimal*, *complete and *repeatable* version.  That means: rip out all the parts that have nothing to do with your problem.  In this case, anything that calls `.css`, all of the `array=[]` code, the unused `k++`  at the end, the unused `var j` (etc) and replace the `$.get` with a simple data setup that sets the exact data you want to match exact html (the provided sample does not show "10 items") - the problem could easily be the data from the `$.get` - eliminate that by replacing it with explicit data

Answer (score 1):

- You increment `k` every time through the loop without modifying the array it's based on.
- You're no longer even *setting* `k`, instead `len`. Post your actual code.
- Crazy amount of duplication in the code that makes it impossible to think about.

Comment: where do I place it then or how do I modify the array?

Comment: I've updated my code to the best I can, please re-check

Comment: @Keren  You're still incrementing `k` at the end of the loop. That's the value being used to check when the loop should end.

Comment: @DaveNewton hard to tell from the nasty indentation and the random extra unmatched `}`, but `k` is currently outside the loop, so the `k++` never actually does anything (from the provided code, which is, of course, incomplete, so could be the problem and there's an extra `}` *before* the `k++` instead of after).